# Static html on a single page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, static, if-statement

I would like to add some basic html page to my homepage that I setup as a static page in wordpress. Well it is a little more complex I would also like to add a jquery plugin only for that page as well. How would I go about doing this, some sort of IF statement I suppose. IF home page add this code IF NOT do not add code.

I know I need to use this **is_home()**

I have tried to do this but nothing outputs, and I am on the homepage so I am not sure what to do. **UPDATE**: Turns out it was not the homepage so I am trying to fix that right now. Ok well I have the home page set to a static page called About and when I am on the home page the else statment runs, that seems backwards to me, what am I doing wrong.

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) {
    echo "<h1>Hello</h1>";
} else {
    // This is not a homepage
    echo "<h1>Goodbye</h1>";
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Simple all I had to do was change **is_home** to **is_front_page**

Comment: you answered your own question.. :)